# How can I play sounds in the Windows Mobile framework?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I started developing in Windows Mobile CE and now I need some stuff off of the coredll.lib but where can I find this library?

edit: 
Okay found it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2\PocketPC\Lib\ARMV4I

But how do I add it to my visual studio project?

edit:

I'll try this instead. What I wanted to do is play a sound by pressing a button. How can I do this in windows mobile? (my development language is c#)

Comment: Change the title of the question and I'll happily answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416468.aspx) (Note, this only works for WM6 and above, for below you should look at the [playsound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909766.aspx) api)

Also you don't include the lib file for coredll in managed code, you use platform invoke. PlaySndSync is in aygshell.dll, and here is the signature:

```
[DllImport("aygshell.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SndPlaySync(string Path, uint Flags);
```

Then you can call SndPlaySync and give it a path to the sound file and the right flags and away you go.